# Can I display multiple screens content using single activity

Tags: android, persistence

Iam developing an android application wherein i need to manage good amount of data. I have 2 doubts.

I planned about 25 screens(pages) in this application. To display each and every screen do I need to create a seperate Activity or can i manage it with single activity. Which option will increase the performance of the application and which one is better.

I have very good amount of data. Do I need to store in SqlLite database or can I store it in string.xml resources file.

While designing the screens are there any constraints that are to be followed.  Please suggest me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) IT is always better to have a separate activity for different tasks as it increase the readability and maintainability of your application code.

2) I would not recommend using one single activity because it will make your class very cluttered and at some point of time it will become very difficult to make further amendments in your code.

3) You can use strings.xml as a replacement of database as it is not meant database purposes. If you have a large amount of data than you have 2 options:

i) If this data is static and not going to change in near future than use sqlite database.
ii) if this data is dynamic in nature and requires frequent update and sync than you must choose a web based service for handling this data.

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Mudit. Data I have is static and will not be changing in near future. If I go for SqlLite database, where will the database be created when I first install the application. and If i delete the application from the mobile, should I delete the database or will it get deleted automatically.

Comment: If you are going for sqlite database, then it will create the application database when ever you want to create it. And yes, it will create the database only first time and after that it will only modify the database. Plus if you uninstall the application, the database will be deleted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

i want to add that you can do this but it's not  a good idea as mudit said ,

you can do something like this :

```
this.setContentView(R.layout.home);
//do some work here ,Click on a button for example
this.setContentView(R.layout.detail);
```